# Areas inside a Triangle

Tags: geometry

$D$ is a point on side $AB$ and $E$ is a point on side $AC$ of triangle $ABC$. $P$ is the point of intersection of $BE$ and $CD$. The area of triangle $ABC$ is $12\text{cm}^2$.

Triangle $BPD$, triangle $CPE$ and the quadrilateral $ADPE$ all have the same area. What is the area of $ADPE$? (see figure)

Using areas I tried to get the ratios of the divided sides.

Let $x$ be the area of the the $BPD$ and $y$ be the area of $BPC$.

$\frac{AD}{DB}=\frac{2x}{x+y}$

$\frac{CE}{EA}=\frac{2x}{x+y}$

$\frac{CP}{PD}=\frac{y}{x}$

$\frac{EP}{PB}=\frac{x}{y}$

I tried connecting $A$ and $P$ and extending it to touch $CB$ but I still cannot find a relationship between $x$ and $y$.

[image]

Comment: Maybe extend AP to BC and apply Ceva's theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$\frac{CE}{EA}=\frac{x}{y_1}=\frac{x+z}{y_1+y_2+x}\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{DB}{AD}=\frac{x}{y_2}=\frac{x+z}{y_1+y_2+x}\tag{2}$$

By comparing (1) and (2) we get:

$$y_1=y_2=\frac x2$$

Replace that in (1) and you'll get:

$$\frac{x}{\frac x2}=\frac{x+z}{\frac x2+\frac x2+x}$$

$$z=3x\tag{3}$$

Use (3) to calculate $x,z$ from the total area of the triangle:

$$x+x+\frac x2+\frac x2 + z=12$$

The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

[image]

See the figure above. By Menelaus theorem, we have $$\frac{CE}{EA}\cdot \frac{AB}{BD} \cdot \frac{DP}{PC}=1.$$
Hence, $$\frac{S_1}{S_2}\cdot \frac{S_3+S_4}{S_4} \cdot \frac{S_3}{S_1+S_2}=1.$$

Notice that $S_1=S_4=S_2+S_3.$ Consequently, $$S_2=S_3=\frac{1}{2}S_1=\frac{1}{2}S_4.$$ Moreover,$$\frac{S_1+S_2+S_3}{S}=\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{S_3}{S_3+S_4},$$
namely, $$\frac{2S_2+S_2+S_2}{S}=\frac{S_2}{S_2+2S_2}.$$ Hence, $$S_2=\frac{1}{12}S.$$
It follows that $$S_2+S_3=2S_2=2\cdot \frac{1}{12}S=\frac{1}{6}S=2 cm^2.$$